# unexpected result in a query in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-6

I’m a beginner in `Laravel` but have a problem at first. I wrote this query and I’m waiting for `Sonya Bins` as result but unexpectedly I see `["Sonya Bins"]`. what’s the problem?

```
Route::get('products', function () {
$articles=DB::table('users')->where('id','2')->get()->pluck('name');
return view('products',compact('articles'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluck` will return array if you want to get only single value then use `value`

```
// will return array
$articles=DB::table('users')->where('id','2')->get()->pluck('name');

//will return string
$articles=DB::table('users')->where('id','2')->value('name');
// output Sonya Bins
```

here is an example from the documentation:

if you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the `value` method. This method will return the value of the column directly:

```
$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');
```

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)
Hope it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` will return the collection.

I think `id` is your primary key.
You can just get the first record, and call its attribute's name:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('id','2')->first()->name;
```

or

```php
DB::table('users')->find(2)->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `pluck()` used to return a String before Laravel 5.1, but now it returns an array.

#### The alternative for that behavior now is `value()`

Try this:

```
Route::get('products', function () {
$articles=DB::table('users')->where('id','2')->get()->value('name');
return view('products',compact('articles'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use the Model + find function + value function.

```
Route::get('products', function () {
  $articles = User::find(2)->value('name');
  return view('products',compact('articles'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you used invalid name for what you pass to view - you don't pass articles but user name.

Second thing is that you use get method to get results instead of first (or find) - you probably expect there is only single user with id = 2.

So to sum up you should use:

```
$userName = DB::table('users')->find(2)->name;

return view('products',compact('userName'));
```

Of course above code is for case when you are 100% sure there is user with id = 2 in database. If it might happen there won't be such user, you should use construction like this:

```
$userName = optional(DB::table('users')->find(2))->name;
```

(`$userName` will be null if there is no such record)

or

```
$userName = optional(DB::table('users')->find(2))->name ?? 'No user';
```

in case you want to use custom string.

Comment: Second thing is that you use get method to get results instead of first - you probably expect there is only single user with id = 2.                                                                                     **id is primary key.***

Comment: @Bashir_Jafari I've added or find - in this case it's better to use find when you search by primary key